# Assigning value to a variable using a old api method to column type field declaration in odoo 8?

Tags: python, odoo-8

I have following code that is a mixture of both new and old api. I need to change the state variable to false in my method if it satisfies a if condition. I am new to open erp and old api methods.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

from openerp import api
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from  openerp import models

class attendance(osv.osv):

```
_name = "attendance.analysis"
_description = "attendance analysis"
EID= fields.integer('Employee ID', required=True),
action= fields.selection([('sign_in', 'Sign In'), ('sign_out', 'Sign Out')], 'Employee Action'),
date= fields.datetime('Employee Date', required=True, select=1),
s2=fields.char("s2", required=True),
state= fields.boolean("state?", default=False)


@api.constrains('s2')
def constrains_action(self):
    if self.s2=='0':
        self.action='sign_in'



@api.constrains('s2')
def constraint_action(self):
    if self.s2 == '1':
        self.action = 'sign_out'

@api.constrains('date')
def constrains_date(self):
    self.env.cr.execute('DELETE FROM attendance_analysis USING attendance_analysis ua2 WHERE attendance_analysis.date = ua2.date AND attendance_analysis.id < ua2.id')




def _altern_si_so(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """ Alternance sign_in/sign_out check.
    Previous (if exists) must be of opposite action.
    Next (if exists) must be of opposite action.
    """
    for att in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        # search and browse for first previous and first next records
        prev_att_ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('EID', '=', att.EID), ('date', '<', att.date),
                                             ('action', 'in', ('sign_in', 'sign_out'))], limit=1, order='date DESC')
        next_add_ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('EID', '=', att.EID), ('date', '>', att.date),
                                             ('action', 'in', ('sign_in', 'sign_out'))], limit=1, order='date ASC')

        results = self.search(cr, uid, [('state','=',att.state)], limit=1, order='date DESC')
        result = self.browse(cr, uid, results, context=context)

        prev_atts = self.browse(cr, uid, prev_att_ids, context=context)
        next_atts = self.browse(cr, uid, next_add_ids, context=context)
        # check for alternance, return False if at least one condition is not satisfied
        if prev_atts and prev_atts[0].action == att.action:

            # How to assign state == True  to change the field value here

            print (result,'hellolllllllllllllll')
            return False


        if next_atts and next_atts[0].action == att.action:  # next exists and is same action
            return False
        if (not prev_atts) and (not next_atts) and att.action != 'sign_in':  # first attendance must be sign_in
            return False
    return True

_constraints = [
    (_altern_si_so, 'Error ! Sign in (resp. Sign out) must follow Sign out (resp. Sign in)', ['action'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. We need to pass the boolean variable through  return self.write method to alter its value

```
def _altern_si_so(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """ Alternance sign_in/sign_out check.
    Previous (if exists) must be of opposite action.
    Next (if exists) must be of opposite action.
    """
    for att in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        state = False
        # search and browse for first previous and first next records
        prev_att_ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('EID', '=', att.EID), ('date', '<', att.date),
                                             ('action', 'in', ('sign_in', 'sign_out'))], limit=1, order='date DESC')
        next_add_ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('EID', '=', att.EID), ('date', '>', att.date),
                                             ('action', 'in', ('sign_in', 'sign_out'))], limit=1, order='date ASC')

        results = self.search(cr, uid, [('state','=',att.state)], limit=1, order='date DESC')
        result = self.browse(cr, uid, results, context=context)

        prev_atts = self.browse(cr, uid, prev_att_ids, context=context)
        next_atts = self.browse(cr, uid, next_add_ids, context=context)
        # check for alternance, return False if at least one condition is not satisfied
        if prev_atts and prev_atts[0].action == att.action:

            return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': True})


            # How to assign state == True  to change the field value here

        if next_atts and next_atts[0].action == att.action:# next exists and is same action

            return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': True})


        if (not prev_atts) and (not next_atts) and att.action != 'sign_in':  # first attendance must be sign_in

            return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': True})


    return True
```